# Compiling an APK file it is part of development or deployment?

Tags: react-native

After about 40 hours of coding I've completed a gig on Fiverr, but now the client is asking me for the apk file. I tried to build it but I've been stuck for hours and now that I get the error I have a very long list of things to try so I'm wondering if I should be doing this at all... I was paid for developing an app, not for compiling or deploying and no other client has ever asked for the apk file.

Plus probably he will want modifications and I'll have to compile again and for some reason he doesn't want to use Expo and test the app easily.

More context: He said he works on a software company and they have too much work so they had to go to fiverr, so he is not ignorant about what software development is.
He never mentioned compiling and the job title is "develop a react native app", there are other sellers who offer develop and compile, develop and deploy, develop and publish, etc, but not me.

So what do you think, is this part of my job?

Comment: This seems pretty opinion-based. But I personally would think that if you have a client and they're not specifically in a technical role themselves, then when they as for "an app" I would assume they want to have something they can run on mobile devices without much more involved technical work.

Comment: Oh sure but adding more context: He said he said he is part of a software company that at the moment is overloaded with work and that's why he went to fiverr, so he is not ignorant about the topic.

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequently encountered problem when I was doing freelance work. I ask myself the following

1. Is it part of the requirements that were agreed upon.
2. Will a reasonable person expect it to be implied from the requirements.
3. Will the usability of the app be substandard if the specified change is not made.

There are usually multiple back-and-forth requests from the client. If I am making a change free of charge, I explain why it is included in our agreement. And when it comes time that the client requests additional things, they are usually very understanding about extra charges.

**My opinion on your case**

If the agreement were to "develop an android app" from no existing code, it is quite reasonably expected that the app runs in a typical physical device rather than an emulator of your choice. On the other hand, it is not reasonably expected to run on their specific customized equipment, or their emulator or compiler of choice.

Hence, an APK as a deliverable, is quite reasonable.